# Build fails while deploying from GitHub to azure app service (node JS Twilio backend)

Tags: node.js, azure, github, cloud, pipeline

I am trying to deploy my backend code to azure app services using the GITHUB actions, the code has been committed and in the action, yml file is also generated, and after clicking the build it fails with an error. **Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**

Answer (score 0):

It depends which Action you used.

It is recommended to start with "[Deploying Node.js to Azure App Service](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-azure/deploying-nodejs-to-azure-app-service)" and its prerequisites (creating an Azure App Service plan, creating a web app, configuring an Azure publish profile and create an `AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE` secret.)

You can then create your workflow, following the example "[`deployments/azure-webapps-node.yml`](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/deployments/azure-webapps-node.yml)" as a possible template, for you to adapt.